# How to set width or precision for seconds with fmt library and chrono

Tags: c++, format, c++20, c++-chrono, fmt

I'm trying to format a duration with [fmt](https://fmt.dev/)'s [chrono impl](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html#chrono-format-specifications) and specify the [precision](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html#grammar-token-sf-precision) for the seconds part.

I'm reading the [documentation](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#date-and-time-formatting) but think i don't understand how to do it; whatever i try, it either doesn't format as expected or the compiler reports an error.

Here's what i tried so far:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ratio>
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#include <fmt/chrono.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, std::nano> const d{3601123456789};
    std::cout << fmt::format("1a {:%H:%M:%S}\n", d);
    std::cout << fmt::format("1_ {: >15%S} <-- width works; precision won't compile\n", d);
    // The fmt docs say that "Precision is valid only for std::chrono::duration types with a floating-point representation type."
    // The following format doesn't compile with "d" whose ticks are represented as integer.
    // It does with "dd" whose ticks are represented as double, but the result is still not as expected.
    std::cout << fmt::format("2_ {:.2%S} <-- this is confusing; precision doesn't work\n", dd);
    std::cout << fmt::format("2_ {: >15.2%S} <-- width works; precision doesn't\n", dd);
}
```

([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/9c6r65r66))

**Edit:**
Just checked with `std::format` on msvc; [the results](https://godbolt.org/z/o3vse6srW) are the same.

Comment: What are you actually trying to print?

Comment: @Barry A wall-clock duration with two digits after the comma of the seconds. The original printf implementation uses "%5u:%05.2f".

Comment: I meant, very specifically, what is the output that you want? `123.46`?

Comment: @Barry I have two cases; usually the durations are bigger. Say, for 
`std::chrono::duration<double, std::micro> d{3601123456}` i'd ideally have `60:1.12` or `60:01.12` but `1:0:1.12` or `01:00:01.12` are fine. At the moment, i'm doing fmod myself and printf each component separately.

Answer (score 4):

To control the width, include an alignment and width specification as the first thing after the ':'.  For example `"{:>20..."` to say align right with width 20.

To control the precision, alter the units of the input duration.  For example to have 3 decimal digits, `floor<milliseconds>(d)`:

```
std::cout << fmt::format("d: {:>20%H:%M:%S}\n", std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::milliseconds>(d));
```

Output:

```
d:         00:02:03.456
```

If you prefer, you can use `{:>20%T}` in place of `{:>20%H:%M:%S}`.

For two fractional digits it would be convenient to create a centiseconds duration:

```
using centiseconds = std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, std::centi>;
std::cout << fmt::format("d: {:>20%T}\n", std::chrono::floor<centiseconds>(d));
```

Getting a little winded from chasing the goalposts here ... ;-)

```
using centiseconds = chrono::duration<int64_t, centi>;
auto d = 3601123456us;
auto m = floor<minutes>(d);
d -= m;
cout << fmt::format("{}:{:%S}", m/1min, floor<centiseconds>(d)) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
60:01.12
```

I got this working for specifying the precision in the format string, but this exits the chrono-type system completely prior to formatting:

```
auto d = 3601123456.us;
auto m = floor<minutes>(d);
d -= m;
cout << fmt::format("{}:{:0>5.2f}", m/1min, d/1s) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
60:01.12
```

Comment: You buried the lede a bit here; the real answer seems to be "you can't directly specific precision, just width, for `%S`" (talking about width is unrelated to the OP's goal, which is purely precision-based). The solution is your definition of `centiseconds` and use of `std::chrono::floor<centiseconds>`.

Comment: Perhaps.  I read "with" as "width" in the title, and assumed it to be a type-o.

Comment: Didn't know about this angle (and sorry for the goalshift; didn't express myself clear enough). I'm still confused by the docs where *"Precision is valid only for std::chrono::duration types with a floating-point representation type."* gave me the impression that it's possible to set the seconds precision in the format string. I'm willing to wait for new versions of fmt but i'm unsure if i read the docs wrong or if the docs are wrong.